# Copying speed is getting slow for some file extensions

Tags: windows, performance, copy-paste

I am using windows 10,
Processor: Intel core i7 2600
Memory: 8GB DDR3 (Primary) 240 GB SSD (Secondary)

My issue is, it is seen that copying speed from another drive is fast in general, but for some type of extensions it is relatively, very much slower (I think).

Now, I was copying android sdk folder, copying speed just raise and falls..when it is copying files like png, xml, html etc the speed is too low, but for exe, or the other file types (relatively large ones) is faster. I just compared and tried to explain by screenshots:

[image]

So, why these types of file copying speed varies, however other files are relevantly faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try and put it simply, a single large file will copy much faster than a directory and groups of files of the same size.

This has to do with the way copying works. Although you're using an SSD, which is much faster than a traditional HDD, the filesystem still has to create file and folder hierarchy. For folders with lots of nested, small files and folders, this can be quite time consuming, as not only do you have to copy the data itself, but also update meta-data such as file/folder update times.

For large files, these things still take time, but once completed the copy speed is dependant on how fast you can transfer data (which as you can see by the large ISO files, is pretty fast).

Thats why for something like the SDK folder, it will rise and fall (rise when it hits a big file it can quickly copy, and fall when it has to create files/folders and update information independent of the data available).